# Problem with CSS DIV align

Tags: html, css

If the doctype declaration is `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 TRANSITIONAL//EN">` what is the best way for horizontal alignment of the DIV's like these:

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">Some text</div></div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#outer{ border-top:1px dotted #999; background-color: #F4F4F4; width:100%;}
#inner{ width:500px;border:1px solid #F00; margin:auto;}
```

The thing that I want to do is the inner DIV align at center (horizontally) inside the outer DIV. This CSS working fine if the doctype declaration is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: What goes wrong with the original doctype? What browsers are you using to test?

Comment: if I open that page using IE8 the inner DIV is align left.

Comment: Actually, that is working on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera, but not on IE. Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to learn a bit about [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which browser you use, but you could change

```
 #outer{ border-top:1px dotted #999; background-color: #F4F4F4; width:100%;}
```

to:

```
 #outer{ border-top:1px dotted #999; background-color: #F4F4F4; width:100%; text-align:center;}
```

Allthough.. I've tested your code on IE8, FireFox and Chrome and all three worked like a charm...

Comment: The problem with text-align:center; is that the all text inside the inner div is align center as well and I want font to align left.

Comment: If that's the only issue, couldn't you just add text-align: left; to the #inner?

Comment: No I can't because there is lots of other things inside that div:(

Comment: I don't get your last comment. You dont want the text to align to the left?
You could always go for the triple-nested-what-am-i-doing-where-div-structure...
whereas the outerinner div (middle) is text-aligned to the left.

But I would *not* recommend it